# creating multiple database and check size of indexeddb before storing data in indexeddb using jsstore in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to create 2 or more databases in indexeddb using jsstore.How can i mention database name while inserting using below

```
        this._connection.insert({...})
```

how to check size of indexeddb before storing data like checking indexeddb 
 exist or not using below lines

```
    JsStore.isDbExist(dbName,function(isExist)
```

can anyone pls guide me

Thanks

Comment: May i know why do you want to check the size in indexeddb?

Comment: I learnt that "if it exceeds 50MB on desktop ,Quota manager will raise error.If user give the permission then only it allows more than 50MB".we need to give permission for unlimited storage while developing without asking user

Comment: Yeah you are right, it depends on browser for assigning quota but its not possible to exceed quota without taking permission from user to store more.

Comment: can you pls guide me how to check indexeddb size in code.if it exceeds the limit,i will delete old data and will store new data